# VolumeSlider not initialized correctly when player loads

Tags: video.js

When I load up the video player for the first time, the volume slider is set at 0 but the volume controls shows its at level 3 (the volume is on so the volume button is correct, the slider is not).  Once you touch the volume slider or the volume button, the issue corrects itself.
How can I get the slider and the volume button to be synchronized the first time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default the volume is set to Max.
Would you tell me which version of video.js do you use?
although check if the following commands are useful for you or not

```
// get the current volume of the media
var howLoudIsIt = myPlayer.volume();

// set the volume to a new value
myPlayer.volume(0.5);

// 0 is off (muted), 1.0 is all the way up, 0.5 is half way.
```